# Prove that A = ∅ if and only if B = A∆B.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Just been trying to prove the following by mathematical deduction for research but having some issues. Mind helping out?

Prove that A = ∅ if and only if B = A∆B.

What I have so far...
A∆B = (A-B)∪(B-A)
= (A∩B^Compliment)∪(B∩A^Compliment)

But not too sure how to explain or go from here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If $A=\emptyset$ then

  - $A\Delta B = (A \setminus  B) \cup (B \setminus A) = (A \cap B^c) \cup (A^c \cap B) = \emptyset \cup B= B$.
- if $B = A\Delta B = (A \cap B^c) \cup (A^c \cap B) = (A \cup B ) \setminus (A\cap B)$ then

  - $B \cap (A \cap B) =\emptyset$ so $(A \cap B) =  \emptyset$
  - $(A \cap B^c) \subset B$ and $B \cap (A \cap B^c) =\emptyset$ so $(A \cap B^c) =  \emptyset$
  - so $A = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B^c) = \emptyset\cup \emptyset= \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to proof an equivalence.
That means you have to proof that if $A=\emptyset$ we have that $B=A\Delta B$.

So let $A=\emptyset$.

Then $A\Delta B=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$. Now set $A=\emptyset$ and we get:

$\emptyset\Delta B=B$.

So this is easy.

For the other implication we have to assume

$B=A\Delta B$, and now we have to show $\emptyset=A$. So a set-equality needs to be proved.

For that we have to show $\emptyset\subseteq A$ (this holds trivially) and $A\subseteq \emptyset$.

Suppose $A\neq\emptyset$. Then $a\in A$.
Now $a\in B$ or $a\notin B$.

If $a\in B$. Then $a\notin A\setminus B$ and $a\notin B\setminus A$. (Why?)

But by assumption $(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)=B$. A contradiction.

If $a\notin B$, then .... [I leave this to you.]

Answer (score 0):

I think such proofs are easier to do with the indicator functions of the sets involved.

Let $\oplus$ be exclusive or, that is, if $x,y \in \{0,1\}$ then $x \oplus y =1$ if $x \neq y$ and $x \oplus y =0$ if $x = y$.

Then it is straightforward to verify that $1_{A \triangle B} = 1_A \oplus 1_B$.

It is also straightforward to verify that $\oplus$ is associative, commutative and $x \oplus x = 0$ and $x \oplus 0 = x$. In particular, $1_A \oplus 1_B \oplus 1_A = 1_B \oplus 0 = 1_B$ and so $A \triangle B \triangle A = B \triangle \emptyset = B$.

Suppose $A=\emptyset$. Then $B \triangle A = B \triangle \emptyset = B$.

Suppose $B = A \triangle B$ then $A \triangle B = A \triangle A \triangle B = \emptyset B = B$.

Answer (score 0):

Symmetric difference satisfies some rules that you can prove for yourself.  $\Delta$ is
commutative, associative, nilpotent ($A\Delta A=\emptyset$) and $A\Delta\emptyset=A.$
Now to your question. $(\Rightarrow)$ is now obvious. Assuming that $B=A\Delta B,$
$$A=A\Delta (B\Delta B)=(A\Delta B)\Delta B=B\Delta B=\emptyset.$$
In proving the associative law, show that an element is in $A\Delta B\Delta C$ iff it is in exactly one or in all three of the sets.